# htaccess redirect url from file to root dir

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've been trying to crack this for a few hours now and now reaching out for an answer/steer if possible.

[image: file structure]

Trying to go from

```
www.domain.co.uk/Product.php?product=solid-oak-dining-table
```

to

```
www.domain.co.uk/solid-oak-dining-table/
```

I tried a lot of Google/other code but the closest I've found is...

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ Product.php?product=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ Product.php?product=$1
```

but I just get a 404. 
Happy to change file locations or setup but the end result has to be the product name on the root.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Do you get a `404` error if you enter `www.domain.co.uk/solid-oak-dining-table/` in your browser?

Comment: That's  correct - I do get a 404 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this redirect with query string

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^Product\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} product=([A-Za-z0-9-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Adding the above code still doesn`t resolve the issue. Maybe it's not codeable?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you are not accounting for the `-` in your query string so you need to change this and from your screenshot it seems you are using windows so you need to enable `mod_rewrite` apache module if it is not already enabled and put this in your `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ Product.php?product=$1
</IfModule>
```

And if you are using `xampp` or `wamp` and files are in a folder called for example `test` your `htaccess` file inside that folder needs to look something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ Product.php?product=$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for that @kellymandem but as that didn`t work I`m starting to think this is not possible. Because how does the browser know the difference between /product-string/ or /about-us/ as they are both strings from the root.

Comment: @alexholsgrove can you help?

Comment: @user2005386 can you please take a screenshot of your website root directory file structure and add it to your question

Comment: @user2005386 I have edited my answer, I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Did a Wordpress install on a dev server to generate an .htacces file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^Product\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /Product.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Works a treat! Hope this helps out someone else. 7 Hours to get a short url!